# Are binance ERC20 token transactions not on the ethereum blockchain?

Tags: web3js, transactions, exchanges, mainnet

I'm using web3js get transaction info on a specific ETH address. When I make the getTransactions call, no info is presented. I then check etherscan and also see that my binance ETH wallet (for deposits) is listed with 1 transaction rather than the multiple transfers I've done on Binance.

Am I missing a key concept here re: how Ethereum works for Binance? Do they run their own network separate to the mainnet?

Appreciate any points to documentation or guides if this is a too obvious question.

Comment: Ethereum and Binance are two separate chains. Contracts and tokens deployed on one of them do not live on the other chain.

Comment: Hmm thanks for the follow up. But then what happens when I transfer ETH from a local wallet to my Binance deposit address? Does the ETH get deposited through a Binance smart contract, but still stay on the Ethereum chain?

Comment: I think it is important to differentiate Binance the exchange ("Binance") and Binance the blockchain ("Binance Smart Chain", "BSC"). If you are depositing ETH into the Binance exchange, you will be sending that ETH to an Ethereum address that is owned by Binance. There should be no BSC interactions when you do this.